# cURL and hyperlink in the page

Tags: html, curl, asp

I need to retrieve a webpage using cURL. However, the page I need has some hidden content that I can show clicking on a hyperlink in that page. My question is, how can I download the page with the entire content using cURL?

I tried putting in a pipe the two curl to download the first page and the to "simulate" the hyperlink but this didn't work. In fact, I get only the page without the hidden content.

Both the first page that the hyperlink point to .asp pages

Thanks

Comment: Does the first page set cookies? What exactly does "doesn't work" mean? error messages? empty result? 404 return code?

Comment: I get this error: <head><title>Object moved</title></head> <body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This object may be found <a HREF="another_page.asp">here</a>.</body>

Comment: And what happens when you use cURL to fetch `another_page.asp`?  I assume in addition to the HTML you posted there's a HTTP response code you have omitted (e.g. 301 or 307 instead of 200 OK)

Answer (score 0):

Use cURL's `-i` or `-v` option to see the [HTTP response codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

Use cURL's `-L` option to follow [redirections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection).

Comment: Thanks. I tried as: curl -i -m 10 --data "param1=xxxx&submit=search" http://www.website.com/result.asp -L http://www.website.com/details.asp where result.asp is the page that I can retrieve and contains the hyperlink to detail.asp. What I get is: HTTP/1.1 302 Object moved
..
Location: findid.asp
Content-Type: text/html
...

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Content-Length: 2864
Content-Type: text/html
Cache-control: private